# Enforce the name of an interface field must equal value of another field

Tags: typescript

I have an interface as follows:

```
export interface DashboardRequest {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  [key:string]: any;
}
```

I was wondering if its possible to enforce that the field name of my third dynamic keyed field must be equal to whatever the value is for the `type` field?

e.g

```
const request:DashboardRequest = {
  name: 'foo';
  type: 'bar;
  bar: 5;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The value for `type` will be set at runtime, TypeScript only supports compile time type checking.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like there must be a better way, but I was able to get something along the lines of what you need in this manner:

```
type DashboardRequest<T extends string> = {
  name: string;
  type: T;
} & { [K in T]: any }

// annoying that you need to pass the type argument here :(
const request: DashboardRequest<'bar'> = {
  name: 'foo',
  type: 'bar',
}
// Compiler error:
//   Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ name: string; type: "bar"; }'
//   but required in type '{ bar: any; }'.


// Edit:
//   Thanks to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir for the idea to use a helper 
//   function to avoid needing to specify the type manually 
const DashboardRequest = {
  create: <T extends string>(o: DashboardRequest<T>) => o
}

// this also gives the correct compiler error
const req = DashboardRequest.create({ name: 'foo', type: 'bar' })
```

Comment: Not a fan of specifying types manually, I usually suggest a helper function to help infer `T`: `function buildDashboardRequest<T extends string>(o: DashboardRequest<T>) {
  return o
}

const request =  buildDashboardRequest({
  name: 'foo',
  type: 'bar',
  bar: ""
})` // no type parameters

Comment: That's a nice way to do it, I'll update my answer to add something similar - thanks Titian